# Internal Server Error when building emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, bug, issue

Since Monday, I am having an issue that is affecting the email creation in Email Studio.

[image].

It happens in the header image of the template and it breaks the layout of the email. Even when trying with different templates (that are working fine in other emails) and building it from scratch the issues persist.

This Internat Server Error is also displayed sometimes when clicking on the Content tab in email studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with some instances of SFMC now.

I have the problem when trying to access the Content tab in Email Studio (cf image below). However it's pretty random.

I've checked on the [Trust Status](https://status.salesforce.com/) website, and it's all green.

[image]

Comment: We are currently within the rollout window of interactive email. It could be connected to that